# When ElseIf condition is true, statements for else if are not happening

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, dateadd

```
Private Sub cbo_Loc_Change()
    Dim Date1 As Date
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = ActiveCell.Row
    If cbo_Loc.Value = TDS Then
    Date1a = Cells(Row, 5).Value
    T1a = DateAdd("ww", 6, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 6).Formula = T1a
    T1b = DateAdd("ww", 8, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 7).Formula = T1b
    ElseIf cbo_Loc.Value = SS Then
    T1a = DateAdd("M", 18, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 6).Formula = T1a
    T2b = DateAdd("m", 6, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 7).Formula = T1b
    End If

End Sub
```

The If- Else statement above should add 6 and 8 weeks to  date1a when the if condition is met, and add 18 and 24 months to date1a when else if condition is met. When ElseIf condition is met, the statements under it are not happening. Can anyone please take a look at it and find what may be the problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of "Date1a" for the ElseIf statement, because when the If statement is evaluated as false, the ElseIf statement will not have the value to "Date1a" assigned. You could do it one of these ways:

```
Private Sub cbo_Loc_Change()

Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Row As Integer

Row = ActiveCell.Row

If cbo_Loc.Value = TDS Then
    Date1a = Cells(Row, 5).Value
    T1a = DateAdd("ww", 6, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 6).Formula = T1a
    T1b = DateAdd("ww", 8, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 7).Formula = T1b
ElseIf cbo_Loc.Value = SS Then
    Date1a = Cells(Row, 5).Value
    T1a = DateAdd("M", 18, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 6).Formula = T1a
    T2b = DateAdd("m", 6, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 7).Formula = T1b
End If
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub cbo_Loc_Change()

Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Row As Integer

Row = ActiveCell.Row
Date1a = Cells(Row, 5).Value

If cbo_Loc.Value = TDS Then
    T1a = DateAdd("ww", 6, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 6).Formula = T1a
    T1b = DateAdd("ww", 8, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 7).Formula = T1b
ElseIf cbo_Loc.Value = SS Then
    T1a = DateAdd("M", 18, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 6).Formula = T1a
    T2b = DateAdd("m", 6, Date1a)
    Cells(Row, 7).Formula = T1b
End If
End Sub
```

Either one will work and should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for the response. I tried both these options.But, it has not fixed the problem. I am looking at it in Debug mode and I see that after the else if condition, the program is directly going to end if. So, are we missing something else here.

Comment: Try this just to see if your ElseIf statement is actually "True":

Above the End If, put:

    Else
        MsgBox("ElseIf is FALSE!")

Comment: You may also need to put quotes around the value strings "TDS" and "SS". For example: cbo_Loc.Value = "TDS" and cbo_Loc.Value = "SS".